# Count data based on users in a given period

Tags: excel, graph, google-sheets, google-forms

I have the following table in my Google Spreadsheet and the following data is being recorded via Google Form,

```
        TimeStamp----      Member Name  Referral To
    ---  8/9/2015 --------  Tom ---------   Jack  
    ---  8/9/2015  -------- Jack --------- Tom
    ---  8/9/2015  -------- Harry -------- Tom
```

Now, i need the number of referrals each member has generated in a given period. 
How can i plot a graph of the responses in the google spreadsheet?
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot table to do so. select your data and From the Data menu, select Pivot table report.
A new sheet named "Pivot Table 1" opens in your spreadsheet with the Report Editor open to the right. This sheet contains an empty pivot table report.
Then Grab members to rows and time stamp to columns and member name into vlaue (count)
you can generate  a chart with from your pivot table.